# BS4 How to get text without using .text?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

This is the source code layout from the website:

```
<div class="address">
    <a href="https://website.ca/classifieds/59-barclay-street/">
        59 Some Street<br />City, Zone 1
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to get the street number, route, and city for Google Geocoding. If I do this

```
>>>article.find('div', {'class': 'address'}).text
'59 Some StreetCity, Zone 1'
```

It takes away the `<br />` and I'm left with no way to split the route from the city. If I do `str().replace('<br />',', ')` then I have to somehow convert it back again to whatever type it was before so I can do `.text` to get the actual text between the `<a href>`, it's inefficient. I'd like to use the functionality that `.text` uses to get the actual text, without the functionality where it removes the `<br>` stuff. I couldn't find a file called `BeautifulSoup.py` in my env, so I'm looking at the BeautifulSoup source code on GitHub, and I can't find a `def text` in there, I don't know where else to look.

Update:

```
articles = page_soup.find('h2', text='Ads').find_next_siblings('article')
for article in articles:
    link = article.find('a')
    br = link.find('br')
    ad_address = br.previous_sibling.strip() + ', ' + br.next_sibling.strip().partition(', Zone ')[0]
    #ad_address = link.br.replace_with(', ').get_text().strip().partition(', Zone ')
```

Comment: you can use `article.find('div', {'class': 'address'}).string`

Comment: That didn't do anything, and prints as `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can locate the `br` delimiter tag and get the *siblings* around it:

```
In [4]: br = soup.select_one("div.address > a > br")

In [5]: br.previous_sibling.strip()
Out[5]: u'59 Some Street'

In [6]: br.next_sibling.strip()
Out[6]: u'City, Zone 1'
```

---

You may also locate the `br` element and replace it with a space using `replace_with()`:

```
In [4]: a = soup.select_one("div.address > a")
In [5]: a.br.replace_with(" ")

In [6]: a.get_text().strip()
Out[6]: u'59 Some Street City, Zone 1'
```

---

Or, you can join all text nodes inside the `a` tag:

```
In [7]: a = soup.select_one("div.address > a")
In [8]: " ".join(a.find_all(text=True)).strip()
Out[8]: u'59 Some Street City, Zone 1'
```

Comment: @vandidant thanks, you may also use `replace_with()` - updated, check it out.

Comment: I have a question about `replace_with()`, I noticed that it was changing the `<br>` in the soup as well as in `a`. In the docs it says that it replaces one string with another, does this mean `replace_with()` is copying the entire soup and deleting the old one each time?

Comment: @vandidant it should only replace a specific `br` with a specified tag or text. In other words, in case of `a.br.replace_with(" ")` a single `br` element inside a specific `a` element would be replaced in the soup. Not sure if the explanation makes things clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
soup.find('div', {'class':'address'}).get_text(separator=u"<br/>").split(u'<br/>')
```

The separator keyword defines inner HTML which concatenates text.

http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/beautifulsoup_ref.html

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted to do, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for link_to_text in links:
   Print link_to_text.get_text()
```